# Magento 2 change validation messsage in checkout address fields

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, validation

Working on Magento 2 checkout validation following is the code

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;

class LayoutProcessor
{
     /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
     public function afterProcess(
         \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
         array  $jsLayout
     ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
        'label' => __('Address'),
        'required' => true,
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 60,
        'type' => 'group',
        'children' => [
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '0',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => true,
                'additionalClasses' => 'additional',
                'label' => __('Street')
            ],
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '1',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => true,
                'label' => __('Number')
            ],
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '2',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => true,
                'label' => __('District')
                ]
            ]

        ];

         return $jsLayout;
     }
 }
```

How to change the vallidation message for the fields Please help

Comment: which message for which field are you looking for change?

Comment: error message in street input field

Comment: what message are you looking for show in this field?

Comment: "Please enter less or equal than 30 symbol" to "30 characters max"

Answer (score 0):

You can change validation message via magento translations.

More information here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Here is ways how to add translations:

**- add new translation to theme**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv (low priority: 3)

More information here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

**- create your own language package**

> app/code/Vendor/MyLocale/en_US.csv (priority: 2)

More information here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-pack

**- use Inline Translation in admin (high priority: 1)**

Priority defines which translation dictionary will loaded first.

---

JS translations stored in static files so you need to re-deploy static content. Or you can just remove js-translation.json files. In magento root folder run

> find pub/static/frontend -name js-translation.json -exec rm -rf {} \;

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to translate the error messages via i18n package.
But there is a bug in Magento up to 2.1.7 at least that won't let you translate these error messages.
You can read this thread for possible solutions. Although I tried all of them and for me none worked so far.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4883