# Magento 2: Change Error message First Name field in Shipping Address

Tags: magento2.3, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

I want to change error messages in Shipping address form to more descriptive on onepage checkout page. For example, I want to change `This field is required` to `First Name is required`.

I am not able to find where these fields are being added in the code. I do see `<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-fieldsets')` in form.html but cant find First and last name in `additional-fieldsets` in layout.xml files.

I also created a `Model/Layoutprocessor.php` in a module but and I am able to override label but not the error messages.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [Magento 2 change validation messsage in checkout address fields](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180465/magento-2-change-validation-messsage-in-checkout-address-fields)